# MySQL: Select last x items of each user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with lots of timestamped entries for each user in my system:

```
id (int, PK)
user_id (int, FK)
date (datetime)
description (text)
other columns...
```

How do I select the last x (e.g. 2) items of each user?
(By last items, I mean of course items sorted desc by date)

Answer (score 0):

Have a correlated sub-query to find a user_id's "second last" date:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
where t1.date >= (select date from tablename t2
                  where t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                  order by date desc
                  limit 1,1)
```

If you want 3 last rows for each user, adjust to `LIMIT 2,1`.

Answer (score 0):

Give a row number based on `user_id` order by descending order of `date`. Then select the rows having row number 1 and 2.

**Query**

```
select t1.id, t1.user_id, t1.`date`, t1.`description` from 
(
    select id, user_id, `date`, `description`, 
    (
        case user_id when @curA 
        then @curRow := @curRow + 1 
        else @curRow := 1 and @curA := user_id end 
    ) as rn 
    from ypur_table_name t, 
    (select @curRow := 0, @curA := '') r 
    order by user_id, `date` desc 
)t1 
where t1.rn in (1, 2); -- or change t1.rn <= 2. Change 2 accordingly
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT t.id, t.user_id, t.`date`, t.`description`
    FROM (SELECT id, user_id, `date`, `description`
            FROM mytable t1
        ORDER BY t1.date desc
           LIMIT X) t    --Change x to the number which you want.
GROUP BY t.id, t.user_id, t.`date`, t.`description`
```

Comment: Can one use `LIMIT` in a subquery?

Comment: @eggyal:- Yes we can. It is not permitted for certain subqueries like: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-restrictions.html

Comment: I suppose what I meant to say was, can one use `LIMIT` in a subquery *in that way*?  Specifically, if one limits the subquery to the two most recent records from the table, then that will surely take place before the grouping in the parent query—and therefore the result won't be the most recent records *per user*?

Comment: But this will return data for max X users, not X rows per user. (And why not do SELECT DISTINCT, when no aggregate functions are involved.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query-

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
               CASE 
                 WHEN @category != t.user_id THEN @rownum := 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 
               END AS rank,
               @category := t.user_id AS var_category
          FROM your_table AS t
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @category := '') r     
      ORDER BY t.user_id,t.date DESC,t.id) x
      WHERE x.rank<=2;
```

Note: x.rank<=2, put here how many rows you need user wise.